# How to link a DLL to a new project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Header.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" {
    DLLIMPORT class Config {
    public:
        static string path;
        static string test;
        static void get_file();
    };
    DLLIMPORT Config* GetConfigInstance();
}
```

dllmain.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <direct.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}



string Config::path;
string Config::test;

void Config::get_file() {
    ifstream infile("cfg.txt");
    char cwd[1024];
    if (_getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get current working directory" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Current working directory: " << cwd << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Reading file: " << cwd << "/cfg.txt" << std::endl;
    string line;
    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        size_t pos = line.find("=");
        string key = line.substr(0, pos);
        string val = line.substr(pos + 1);
        if (key == "img_path") {
            path = val;
        }
        else if (key == "test") {
            test = val;
        }
    }
}

Config* GetConfigInstance()
{
    return new Config();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "Header.h"

int main() {
    HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("Util_aoi_model.dll"));
    if (hinstLib == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load DLL" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    typedef Config* (*GetConfigInstanceFunction)();
    GetConfigInstanceFunction getConfigInstance = (GetConfigInstanceFunction)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "GetConfigInstance");
    if (getConfigInstance == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get address of GetConfigInstance function" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    Config* config = getConfigInstance();
    config->get_file();
    std::cout << "img_path: " << Config::path << std::endl;
    std::cout << "test: " << Config::test << std::endl;

    FreeLibrary(hinstLib);

    return 0;
}
```

I have been building a `.dll` and `.lib`, but when I use another `.sln` to call them, it will show the error:

> unresolved external symbol

I am sure I add the include path and lib path.

The link input has the `.lib`'s name.

Can anyone help me to fix the error?

The `header.h` and `dllmain.cpp` files are in the same project and build a `.dll` and `.lib`.

Another `main.cpp` is in a new project in which I am trying to use the DLL function `get_file()`.

Comment: I recommend you to refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170), it explains very clearly how to link a DLL in a project.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach won't work as written. In the 2nd solution, the compiler is looking for the implementation of `get_file()`, which it won't have access to. Also, you can't use non-trivial types like `std::string` across the DLL boundary.

You need to remove all data members from `Config`, and make all of its methods be non-static pure virtual methods. In other words, make `Config` be an abstract interface. And then have the DLL implement that interface using a separate class, which it can then instantiate and return a pointer to.

Try this:

Header.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef BUILDING_DLL
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" {

class Config {
public:
    virtual const char* get_path() = 0;
    virtual const char* get_test() = 0;
    virtual void get_file() = 0;
};

DLLIMPORT Config* GetConfigInstance();

}
```

dllmain.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"

#define BUILDING_DLL
#include "Header.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <direct.h>

using namespace std;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

class ConfigImpl : public Config {
public:
    string path;
    string test;
    const char* get_path() override;
    const char* get_test() override;
    void get_file() override;
};

const char* ConfigImpl::get_path() {
    return path.c_str();
}

const char* ConfigImpl::get_test() {
    return test.c_str();
}

void ConfigImpl::get_file() {
    ifstream infile("cfg.txt");
    char cwd[1024];
    if (_getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == nullptr) {
        cerr << "Failed to get current working directory" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Current working directory: " << cwd << endl;
    cout << "Reading file: " << cwd << "/cfg.txt" << endl;
    string line;
    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        size_t pos = line.find("=");
        string key = line.substr(0, pos);
        string val = line.substr(pos + 1);
        if (key == "img_path") {
            path = val;
        }
        else if (key == "test") {
            test = val;
        }
    }
}

Config* GetConfigInstance()
{
    static ConfigImpl impl;
    return &impl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "Header.h"

int main() {
    HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("Util_aoi_model.dll"));
    if (hinstLib == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load DLL" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    typedef Config* (*GetConfigInstanceFunction)();
    GetConfigInstanceFunction getConfigInstance = (GetConfigInstanceFunction)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "GetConfigInstance");
    if (getConfigInstance == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get address of GetConfigInstance function" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    Config* config = getConfigInstance();
    config->get_file();
    std::cout << "img_path: " << config->get_path() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "test: " << config->get_test() << std::endl;

    FreeLibrary(hinstLib);

    return 0;
}
```